# Wordpress displaying the header and footer on all pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Is there a way I can make the header and footer appear on all pages without placing get_header(); or get_footer(); in each of the separate page files? Is there something I can do in the loop or somewhere else that automatically does this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to show `get_header()` and `get_footer()` to all the pages. For that you just mention `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in each custom template you have created. By default you can place it inside `page.php` file.

Also if you want to use custom header and custom footer , then you need to create header-custom.php and footer-custom.php file and call them inside any template like the following.

```
get_header('custom');
get_footer('custom');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with just placing them in the page.php file of your theme.